# javax.microedition lib

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Can anyone suggest why the compiler refuses to understand

```
import javax.microedition.io.Connector
```

It even doesn't show it in the package list when I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>`?
I just start an existing project with code that tries to import that package, but the compiler said that it can't be resolved.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused by a missing BB jar file in your project settings. In Package Explorer navigate to "JRE System Library" folder and make sure that net_rim_api.jar is there.